# ArangoDB query with multiple attributes and FULLTEXT search

Tags: arangodb, arangojs

Below is my collection structure, has 3 collection, image, category and tags

I want to filter all "images" which has keyword  (FULLTEXT search) like "cow" and belongs to "animals" category and tagged with "photo"

How can I do this filter with ArangoDB,  I am using nodejs / foxx . Please help.

```
image{
filename:"myphoto.jpg",
filepath:"/opt/data/949b3e6194bf6f0ef3eb367a615826f8"
categories:[category/6401, category/6402],
tags:[tags/1002],
keywords:"photo green cow"
}

category{
    _id:'category/6401',
   name:"animals"
}

category{
    _id:'category/6402',
   name:"living things"
}

tags{
    _id:'tags/1002',
   name:"photo"
}

tags{
    _id:'tags/1003',
   name:"colors"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a request :

```
FOR i IN FULLTEXT(image, "keywords", "cow") // First search for fulltext
    FOR cat IN category // Then Loop on all categories
    FILTER cat.name == "animals" // Filter by name
    FILTER POSITION(i.categories, cat._id) == true // Join
    FOR tag IN tags // Then Loop on all tags
        FILTER tag.name == "photo" // Filter by name
        FILTER POSITION(i.tags, tag._id) == true // Join
        RETURN i // Return all images found
```

You must have a fulltext index set to your image.keywords field

Comment: Thank you,  I will try this and let you know